# Does Maven artifact metadata reveal whether artifact is stable release?

Tags: maven

Do Maven artifacts or their metadata deployed to a remote repository allow to reliably determine whether an artifact is a stable release?

Snapshots have the suffix `SNAPSHOT`, however there are also alphas, betas and pre-releases, and the naming is not necessarily consistent, e.g.:

- [`5.0-alpha1`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents.core5/httpcore5/5.0-alpha1)
- [`5.1-beta2`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents.core5/httpcore5/5.1-beta2)
- [`3.0.0-M5`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/3.0.0-M5) (maybe this is actually a stable release?)
- [`4.13-rc-2`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit/4.13-rc-2)
- [`5.7.0-RC1`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-api/5.7.0-RC1)

https://mvnrepository.com highlights non-release versions differently, however maybe it is just looking for certain keywords?
[image: mvnrepository.com screenshot]
([source](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents.core5/httpcore5))

Comment: The question which results from that is: How do you define a stable release?

Comment: In Maven SNAPSHOT's don't have often `SNAPSHOT` as suffix ... they have *always* the suffix...

Comment: @khmarbaise, I have corrected the incorrect statement about snapshots, thanks. I would say it is the creator of an artifact who defines whether it is stable. There must be a reason why the creator choose to release something as "beta" instead of as full release, and I would assume this is (not yet extensively tested) stability.

Comment: I can say for maven-surefire-plugin version 3.0.0-M5 I'm using it in production...I call it stable enough...tested enough? The plugins etc. have a large test suites...I would 2.500 tests? https://ci-builds.apache.org/job/Maven/job/maven-box/job/maven-surefire/job/master/45/testReport/ from my point of view very good...

Comment: @khmarbaise Re „they have always the suffix...“ – This applies just to the local Maven repo. On remote repos managed by a Repository Manager snapshots usually have a timestamp + sequence qualifier, e.g. Nexus: „[_where the actual number used is composed of a date/timestamp and an enumerator_](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/formats/maven-repositories)“.

Comment: @GeroldBroser Simply wrong that's only defined by the repository manager ... from outside you request always a `-SNAPSHOT`... The timestamp + #. is only made to make them storable on server side and prevent collisions...Maven does not know something about a timestamp etc. Maven knows only `-SNAPSHOT`...

Comment: @khmarbaise From a Maven-puristic you're right. But there's (much) more than just Maven in a dev environment. That's what I wanted to express.

Comment: All tools handle it that way... they deploy either releases or SNAPSHOT's and the repository managers handle things for storing etc. on their own.  I know there is much more than Maven  for example BuildR, SBT, Kobalt, Ant, Gradle, Buck, Bazel etc. to mention only a few...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [POM Reference](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html) which has detailed explanations about version numbers beginning at section [Dependency Version Requirement Specification](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Dependency_Version_Requirement_Specification):

> If version strings are syntactically correct [Semantic Versioning 1.0.0](https://semver.org/spec/v1.0.0.html) version numbers, then in almost all cases version comparison follows the precedence rules outlined in that specification. [...]
>
> [...]
>
> When version strings do not follow semantic versioning, a more complex set of rules is required. [...] This gives a sequence of version numbers (numeric tokens) and version qualifiers (non-numeric tokens) with "." or "-" prefixes.

So, `alpha1`, `beta2`, `M5`, `rc-2`, `RC1` are:

a) for „*A pre-release version* [...] *denoted by appending an arbitrary string immediately following the patch version and a dash.*“ according to point 4. of the [Semantic Versioning Specification (SemVer)](https://semver.org/spec/v1.0.0.html),

b) all  *qualifiers* for (pre-)*releases*, not snapshots, where `M` stands for [*milestone*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_release_life_cycle#Pre-alpha).

Content-wise you only can trust the artifact creator(s) that they took a proper qualifier that represents the actual status of the artifact.

Comment: Thanks, the POM Reference was most helpful because it defines: "except for the following tokens which come first in this order", for which the SemVer ordering does not apply. These actually list all the examples I had in my answer.